# what if the timelock is in the past?

Tags: bitcoin-core, consensus, timestamp, locktime

I just started learning about bitcoin scripting and wonder:

- what if the timelock in CLTV is in the past?
- what if the timelock in nLocktime is equal to 500.000?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the `nLockTime` is less than or equal to the next block height, it can be included in the next block.

To explicitly answer your questions:

- The `CLTV` op restricts the `nLockTime` field of the spending transaction, therefore if it is set in the past the condition is already fulfilled.
- If the `nLockTime` field of a transaction is set to `500 000` it is valid to be included in any block which height is superior or equal to `500 000`.
  This basically means any block right now if there is no block chain reorganization deeper than `160 000` blocks :).

This mechanism was cleverly used to discourage reorgs. [First introduced in the bitcoin-core wallet](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/pull/2340), but now most wallets set the `nLockTime` field of their transactions to the next block.
This prevents, in a future where miners would mainly be compensated for their work by transaction fees, a pernicious incentive to rollback the last block if it included a high fee-paying transaction.

Answer (score 1):

As darosior says you can only impose a timelock such that Bitcoin can be spent **after** a certain block height. You can't impose a timelock such that Bitcoin can only be spent **before** a certain block height.

A related question is this [one](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/95879/with-miniscript-why-is-it-not-possible-to-invert-conditions-with-something-like) on the possibility of a `not()` condition in Miniscript. As Pieter Wuille stated in that answer:

> The nSequence and nLocktime fields themselves do observe time, and can only express larger-than constraints. Bitcoin transaction validity should be monotonic: once valid, absent double-spend, they remain valid.

> The alternative would be a logistical nightmare. All mempool transactions would need to be reevaluated every block. Reasoning about validity of unconfirmed transactions would be a pain (e.g. what if you're paid using a tx spending the output of a soon-to-be expired tx?)